# how to create prototype bean when it is referred in singleton bean?

Tags: java, spring, dependency-injection, frameworks

Assume we are using spring ro create objects. We have declared class A as singleton and it has reference of B which is in prototype scope. In this case B also act as singleton with A's object. How to create new B when ever we use A(when calling A).

Answer (score 0):

This can not be handled through Dependency Injection/Inversion Of Control. Take a look at [Method Injection](http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/3.1.x/spring-framework-reference/html/beans.html#beans-factory-method-injection) concept.

Answer (score 0):

You can use lookup method injection for this.
Lets take an example :

```
@Component
@Scope("singleton")
public abstract class StudentInfo {
    @Value("girraj")
    private String firstName;
    @Value("gupta")
    private String lastName;
    public String getFirstName() {
        return firstName;
    }
    public void setFirstName(String firstName) {
        this.firstName = firstName;
    }
    public String getLastName() {
        return lastName;
    }
    public void setLastName(String lastName) {
        this.lastName = lastName;
    }

    @Lookup
    public abstract Address getAddress();

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return "StudentInfo [firstName=" + firstName + ", lastName=" + lastName + ", address=" + getAddress() + "]";
    }

}
```

This is your student info class. Here we are injecting Address class as dependency and every time when ever you will call. StudentInfo object will always be same but Address object will be new. This is introduced in 5.1.6 release but you can use xml based configuration for same which was available in earlier versions if you are using older version of spring.